# C# How to duplicate each row in Excel

Tags: c#, excel

I have problem how to duplicate each row in excel by defined number in C#.

So If I have Table like this

A B C D E F
1 2 3 4 5 6

And if I set variable counter to 2 I'll get this result:

A B C D E F
A B C D E F
A B C D E F
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6

I know how to copy whole row to another row, but I have problem with duplicating..

Comment: And the problem is.. ? And the code you tried is where ?

Comment: What is the difference between copy/pasting a row and duplicating a row?

Comment: Foreach row in your table, Copy your row from your sheet to a new row. Repeat that copy N times.

Comment: Problem is overwriting second row or next rows by copy and paste, I need take first row (A B C D E F) duplicate N times below to first row and then move to (1 2 3 4 5 6) and duplicate N times below the same row .

I gues that problem is in for loop

I have like for (var i=1; i < duplicateValue; i++) {
sourceRange = "A" + i + ": B" + i;
destRange = "A" + i+1 + ":B" + i+1;
 currentSheet.Range[sourceRange].Copy(currentSheet.Range[destRange]);
}

Answer (score 0):

Unless I missed the mark, I think something as simple as this would do the job:

```
int repeatRows = 2;

long rowCount = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
long rowIndex = 1;

while (rowIndex <= rowCount)
{
    ws.Rows[rowIndex].Copy();
    Range pasteRange = ws.Range[string.Format("A{0}:A{1}", rowIndex + 1, 
        rowIndex + repeatRows)].EntireRow;
    pasteRange.Insert();
    rowIndex += (repeatRows + 1);
    rowCount += repeatRows;
}
```